# How can I display children of the child page on the homepage? (Wagtail / Django)

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am building a simple blog app using Wagtail.
I am trying to display a list of the blog post on the home page. It works well when I display them on the blog page so a direct parent, however when I want to do the same on the home page so the parent of the parent I got stuck.

The tree structure of the page is following:

```
1. Home:
   1.1 Blog
     1.1.1 Post1
     1.1.2 Post2
   1.2 About
```

I tried to add get_context method:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    templates = "home/home_page.html"

    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['strony'] = BlogPage.get_children(self)
        return context
```

However, this code does not return a list of blog post, but actually the list of children of homepage - so Blog and About pages.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to be sure without seeing more of your code, but I think you want something like:

```
context['blog_pages'] = BlogPage.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked but not with BlogPage but with the PostPage.Objects.All()

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! It worked but not with BlogPage but with the PostPage.Objects.All()